# Obtaining a valid subgradient

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, subgradient

I have a nonconvex function, which could be non-smooth in some places. I also have the expression for computing the gradient vector of the function. This vector is valid as a gradient wherever the function is smooth. This vector doesn't blow-up when the function is at a non-smooth point. That being the case, could I use this vector as a valid sub-gradient at that non-smooth point?

Comment: is the function convex? If yes, please edit your question accordingly

Comment: It is a nonconvex function. I have updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: if it is non-convex, what definition of subgradient are you using?